# Forwarding E-Mail inserted with GMail Users.messages: insert API

Tags: email, gmail, gmail-api

I'm using GMail's API: [Users.messages: insert](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert), in order to insert EMails into my GMail mailbox.

Additionally I've configured mail forwarding from my mailbox to another GMail account.

**Unfortunately** the mail inserted with GMail insert API are not forwarded.

Will be glad for any help on that subject :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`users.messages.import()`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/import) to upload messages and have forwarding rules executed on them.  insert() bypasses most of the automatic mail processing, including forwarding and filters.

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work. message arrives to inbox but is not forwarded.